# XmlPad problems with XPath for finding duplicate nodes

Tags: duplicates, xpath

[EDIT]  It seems that there is a bug in the XML Editor I'm using (XmlPad) that prevents the Xpath query from returning the correct results.  I've tested the same query using two  online tools (http://www.zrinity.com/xml/xpath/xpath.cfm and http://www.futurelab.ch/xmlkurs/xpath.en.html) and it seems to work.  biziclop also commented that the query works correctly in Oxygen.

I've got this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <itemlist>
    <item>
      <code>0001.0.00</code>
      <category>709</category>
    </item>
    <item>
      <code>0001.0.00</code>
      <category>709</category>
    </item>
    <item>
      <code>0002.0.00</code>
      <category>708</category>
    </item>
  </itemlist>
  <itemlist>
    <item>
      <code>0016.0.00</code>
      <category>52</category>
    </item>
    <item>
      <code>0016.0.00</code>
      <category>52</category>
    </item>
    <item>
      <code>0016.0.00</code>
      <category>51</category>
    </item>
    <item>
      <code>0016.0.00</code>
      <category>50</category>
    </item>
    <item>
      <code>0869.0.00</code>
      <category>52</category>
    </item>
    <item>
      <code>0869.0.00</code>
      <category>51</category>
    </item>
    <item>
      <code>0869.0.00</code>
      <category>50</category>
    </item>
  </itemlist>
</root>
```

I want find all items where the previous item has the same category.

This Xpath query:

```
//item[category = preceding-sibling::item[1]/category]
```

returns the following nodes:

```
<item>
  <code>0001.0.00</code>
  <category>709</category>
</item>
<item>
  <code>0016.0.00</code>
  <category>52</category>
</item>
<item>
  <code>0869.0.00</code>
  <category>52</category>
</item>
```

The last item node in the result set is incorrect, because the value of the previous item's category in the **input** is not 52 so it should not be returned.

Is there an Xpath query that will return the results I want?

Comment: I tested it in Oxygen and it returns only two nodes, as it should.

Comment: Hmmmm... it's possibly a bug in XmlPad then.  I'll try it out in a different app.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: This is not reproducible for me.

Comment: Not reproducible in XmlPad?  Which version?  If it's the same as mine I'll post a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath is absolutely correct. I've tested it with **Saxon** XSLT processor as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:copy-of select="//item[category 
            = preceding-sibling::item[1]/category]"/>   
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With results:

```
<item>
   <code>0001.0.00</code>
   <category>709</category>
</item>
<item>
   <code>0016.0.00</code>
   <category>52</category>
</item>
```

You might want also try alternatives:

```
//item[category = ./preceding-sibling::item[1]/category]
/root/itemlist/item[category = ./preceding-sibling::item[1]/category]
```